# How to open a 100% witdh div when click on an element of the list (bootstrap/Sass/Js using)

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I'm desesperated and I rally need your help...

As a picture is more than words :
[here what I wanna do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHWcY.jpg)

I want to display a list of  with background image (3 per line), and when I click on one, I want to open a div which contain the description of the image clicked. I want this div to do 100% width of the parent container. And when the dis is opening, the  below are pushed down, and pushed up on closing... And I want this to be responsive. The problem is I have no idea how to do...!!!! I don't even found example of what I want on another web site !

I'm using bootstrap, sass, js/jquery. If you have any idea please help me :'( Because all I tried didn't worked :'(

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I found this but not what I want [see example](http://projet.audreyhossepian.fr/workout/fc.html)

Comment: It was my code but it's okay I found a solution thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/codrops/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview

Here is the solution (code and demo from codrops)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your end goal is here but here's a solution that will have 3 anchor tags across and a hidden div below. When an anchor is clicked, it will send the description to the div below and show it. By default, a div will be a 100% width block.

```
<style type="text/css">
    section > div > a {
        width: 33.3%; 
        display: block; 
    }
    section .description {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section > div > a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var desc_block = $(this).closest('section').find('description');
        desc_block.html($(this).data('description');
        desc_block.show();    
    });
}
</script>
<section>
    <div>
        <a data-description="Your description to show below"></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="description"></div>
<section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found something like that but it's not good for the responsive :
[see example](http://projet.audreyhossepian.fr/workout/fc.html)